# Server on node.js + android client + json file

Tags: java, android, node.js, server, client

I have a RESTful API on Node.js that works with a json file. The problem lies in the fact that it does not come out to write a simple android client (previously it did not work with Java and in the android studio for the first time), which could work with the api of my server, or rather change this json file itself:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Tom","password":24},{"id":2,"name":"Bob","password":27},{"id":3,"name":"Alice","password":"23"}].
```

I read both about gson and valley and httpurlconnection, but in the end it does not work even just to connect to the server, there is no understanding of how to do it correctly.

I ask for help with writing code, links to useful articles, or just advice.

P.s. The server-client experience is only from Qt, there with sockets somehow it was easier ....

I apologize for my english, thank you, google translate

Answer (score 0):

if I get you correctly, you want to get this data in your android app
if that so i recommend using [**Retrofit**](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) you should made an Interface class first then add something like this in your Interface:

```
 @GET("yourapi.com/url")
    Call<YourDataModelClass> GET_MY_DATA(
            @Header("Authorization") String key);
```

and please be aware that you should add what your api requires too, I've only added header here for just an example.

then in your data model Class, you should add something like this:

```
public class YourDataModelClass {
    private Boolean action;
    private String _token;
    private boolean need_login;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;

    public boolean isNeed_login() {
        return need_login;
    }

    public Boolean getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public String get_token() {
        return _token;
    }
    public String password() {
        return password;
    }
     public String name() {
         return name;
    }
    public int id() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

let me know how it goes. and goodluck